# Hashset for caching objects and querying based on ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hashset

If I have a class `Foo`:

```
public class Foo {
    int FooId;
    string FooName;
    // etc;
}
```

And I want to cache them and query them based on Id, I currently do something like this:

```
private List<Foo> cachedFoos;

public Foo GetFoo (int fooId) {
    Foo foo = cachedFoos.FirstOrDefault(s => s.FooId == fooId)
    if (foo != null){
        return foo;
    } 
    else {
       foo = GetFooFromDb;
       cachedFoos.Add(foo);
       return foo;
    }
}
```

But I think I should be using a HashSet here so I don't have to worry about concurrency issues (inserting duplicate Foos).  HashSets query by objects though where I need to query by the PK.  Should I somehow be leveraging HashSets here?

Comment: "_HashSets query by objects though_" what do you mean? a `HashSet<T>` is an `IEnumerable<T>` just like List. So you can use LINQ methods on it the same way you do with list.

Comment: I don't think HashSet will help you. Do you mean Dictionary?

Comment: use a `Dictionary<int, Foo>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ID as a key and are afraid of concurrency issues, I think [`ConcurrencyDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) is the class you need and it also has a very useful function [`GetOrAdd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(v=vs.110).aspx)

```cs
private ConcurrencyDictionary<int, Foo> cachedFoos = new ConcurrencyDictionary<int, Foo>();

public Foo GetFoo (int fooId) {
    return cachedFoos.GetOrAdd(fooId, GetFooFromDb);
}
```

Note however, that famously there are two hard problems in programming: naming and caches invalidation. And my sample doesn't begin to tacle cache invalidation. Moreover, you should not roll over your own caching unless you understand what you are doing very very good. Why don't use something more standard that already includes caching such as EntityFramework?